# How to calculate melting time of a fuse?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current

I tried to look up how to calculate the time it takes for a [fuse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuse_(electrical)) to melt, but wasn't able to understand many of the terms like "*let-through current*", $I_{\text{rms}}$, etc..

Please help me out with a derivation for melting time of a fuse.  Also explain the terms used.

Comment: "I rms": root mean square of current. One calculates the mean of I*I and then takes the square root, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square .

Comment: Not entirely sure but I think let-through current is the amount of current a fuse allows to pass through? And when it becomes too high it begins the procedure to short the circuit.

Comment: Can please derive it? I'am facing much difficulty

Answer (score 1):

The time to fuse will depend on multiple factors that you probably don't know:

- The resistance of the fuse (likely variable with temperature)
- The heat of fusion of the fuse material
- The diameter of the fuse wire
- The thermal conductivity of the material surrounding the fuse
- The thermal conductivity and thermal mass of whatever's connected to the two ends of the fuse
- Whether any convective heat transfer (air flow) is cooling the fuse wire, and how much

Practically, the fuse is likely designed empirically, and even the designers don't accurately know all these factors.

However, a well specified fuse will likely have a fuse timing curve in its datasheet like this:

[image]

This curve tells you directly, given a chosen amount of over-current applied to the fuse, how long it will take to fuse in typical conditions.

As you can see, these particular fuses are designed to fuse at about 2x their rated currents, and with small over-currents might take as long as 100 s to fuse.

Comment: Wow, is this actual data for fuses of various amp ratings? It looks like a 1.0 Amp fuse can support a current of 2 Amps indefinitely and for 3 Amps it would take about 5 seconds to blow, and for 4 Amps it would still take over a second to blow. Are these curves for fast-blow fuses or slow-blow fuses?